# The addition of a sequence of exponents Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

A very simple for loop would suffice in any of the previous languages I know

```
amount = 0

for(r=0, r<64, r++){

    amount+=2^r

}
```

How would I go about this in Haskell. I have tried a recursive function.

Comment: First build an infinite sequence of powers of two, then grab the first 64 of them, then sum that result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to get an infinite list and then take out only the first 64 of them and finally sum it like this

```
main = print $ sum (take 64 [2 ^ x | x <- [0..]])
-- 18446744073709551615
```

Here,

```
[2 ^ x | x <- [0..]]
```

this part is supposed to generate an infinite list, where `x` takes the values from `0` to infinity and for every value of `x` we get the corresponding `2 ^ x`. Since we need only the first 64 items, we use `take 64` to get only them and add all of them with the builtin `sum` function.

Or even simpler, as Zeta suggests, we can generate only the first 64 numbers and add them like this

```
main = print $ sum [2 ^ x | x <- [0..63]]
```

Comment: I think `main = print $ sum $ take 64 [2 ^ x | x <- [0..]]` would be better in this specific scenario

Comment: @Arnon Thank you :-) In Python it is `2 ** x`. I didn't know about `^` in haskell.

Comment: Seems rather complicated, compared to `sum . map (2^) $ [0..63]`.

Comment: `2**x` works in Haskell, but it returns a `Floating` which I presonally detest >:(

Answer (score 1):

Since what you are doing is to add up the first 64 values from a list of powers of 2, the `fold` functions would be suited to the task. You can use the `foldl'` function as follows:

```
import Data.List(foldl')

sumfunc :: Int -> Integer
sumfunc x = foldl' (+) 0 $ map (2 ^) [0..x-1]
```

The part after the dollar sign is used to build the list of the first 64 powers of 2. The part before the dollar sign then serves to add the values together with an initial value of 0. Note that the resulting value is specifed as an `Integer` to avoid overflow errors.

Comment: You might want to use `foldl'`. `foldl` will build up a big thunk, especially for large `x` values. For `64`, the `foldl'` version uses about an eighth of the memory of the `foldl` version on my computer.

Comment: Yeah I was originally going to suggest `foldl'` too but since my version of GHC doesn't support it I just tested with `foldl` and posted that instead.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't support it? It looks like it's been in since at least version 6.2.1. It's in `Data.List` and it's not imported by default.

Comment: Oh no! That was it - I wasn't importing `Data.List` and stupidly assumed it wasn't supported. Edited answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

You can code a similar loop in Haskell:

```
Prelude> import Data.List (foldl')

Prelude Data.List> foldl' (\amount r -> amount + 2^r) 0 [0..63]

18446744073709551615
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a geometric series:

```
amount = a
for (r=0, r<N, r++) {
  amount += k^r
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
amount = (k^N - 1)/(k - 1) + a
```

which clearly evaluates in constant time.  In your case, the expression is simply `2^64-1`

Comment: While this is strictly correct, the question is evidently about translating the imperative concept of a for loop to Haskell.

Comment: It's not just "strictly correct", it demonstrates a different concept and provides an alternative, and in this case, far more efficient answer.  Learning new approaches in programming can be just as useful as learning how to implement the first approach you think of.  Key word is "useful" (vis à vis up-voting/down-voting).